# "appcmd start site" command fails with message "The object identifier does not represent a valid object."

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, appcmd

When I run

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe start site /site.name:"Some_site_name"
```

on Windows Server 2008 R2, it fails with message

```
ERROR ( hresult:800710d8, message:Command execution failed.
The object identifier does not represent a valid object.
)
```

... although the site exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to check if there is a binding present! Site without bindings cannot be started and the utility thinks that "The object identifier does not represent a valid object." is a good way to remind me of this.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this error it was because I had a typo in Advanced Settings>Enabled Protocols.

Instead of specifying "http,NET.TCP" I had "http.NET.TCP" (note the comma/period difference) and that caused this error too.

It took me ages to spot it, so I'd thought I'd publish the solution just in case there's another, equally shortsighted, developer out there, scratching their head.